# Weierstrass Elliptic functions

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, periodic-functions, elliptic-functions

Please suggest a good book on preliminary Weierstrss elliptic functions or some link from where I can learn about them in details. Please help.

Comment: I like the chapter in Copson's book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Theory-Functions-Complex-Variable/dp/0198531451/

Comment: I like _Lectures on the Theory of Elliptic Functions_ by Harris Hancock. It was reprinted by Dover Publications. It introduces both Jacobi and Weierstrass elliptic functions and gives the connections between them.

Comment: Thank you. Will find out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take any book on elliptic curves, as they will have an at length discussion of Weierstrass elliptic functions and some of their basic properties (to build a basic theory for elliptic curves). For example, Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* or Husemoller's *Elliptic Curves* or the alike. Most books on complex analysis will have in their later chapters a bit on these as well, if only in exercises. So take your favorite complex analysis book and check the later chapters. There is also Lang's *Elliptic Functions*. Also, a Google search with these words tagged with PDF will also bring up plenty of great summaries, depending on the level of detail you would like. For example, 'elliptic curve Weierstrass function pdf' will bring up many things that you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will go through the texts definitely.